# Why can't C++ set iterators be cast to bool?

Tags: c++, stl, casting, boolean, set

For an STL set (s), it seems like you should be able to say:

```
if(s.find(x)) {
    //Something
}
```

as opposed to

```
if(s.find(x) != s.end()) {
    //Something
}
```

Furthermore, if set-iterators could be cast to bool (true if the internal pointer is not null), you would be able to.  Why don't STL set iterators have this simple functionality?  Was this intentionally left out?

CLARIFICATION:

Alternatively, set's could just have a set::contains(x) method which returns a bool directly, but this doesn't seem to be implemented either.  I know it's only a couple characters, but in the case where s is a return value from some function, this can be frustrating because of the need to create a temporary variable, ie (supposing m is of type `map<int,set<int>>`)

```
const set<int>& s = m[i];
return s.find(x) != s.end();
```

as opposed to

```
return m[i].contains(x);
```

or

```
return m[i].find(x);
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize the count() method could be used as contains().  Voted to close since this question doesn't properly phrase what I really should have asked: Do STL::set's have a "contains" method?

Comment: Why should you be able to write `s.find(x)`? Iterators are positions and there doesn't seem to be a good reason why a position has a Boolean state.

Comment: Semantically, `end` iterators and `null` are two different concepts

Comment: @DietmarKühl: One could say the same about pointers, but they can be implicitly converted to `bool`!

Comment: "true if the internal pointer is not null" -- woah there. Who says that a set iterator is equal to end if and only if its "internal pointer is null"? Not that it really affects the main part of your question, but that's an unwarranted assumption about the implementation of `set`.

Comment: Use [`set::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: that could be an answer if it's the real rationale ("`set` already has a simple membership test in boolean context, it doesn't need another"). But it would still leave the question why `multiset` doesn't provide this proposed convenience feature :-)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: OK, that's a fair point. Of course, `s.end()` actually is more of a position than a null pointer: if the set is non-empty, you can get an element using `--s.end()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Agreed.  The pointer analogy does not hold here; a pointer-to-end-of-array (for example) is not a null pointer ;)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't believe it is the rationale. In fact I'm quite certain it's not.  I was just offering up an alternative.

Comment: "could just have a `set::contains(x)` method which returns a bool directly, but this doesn't seem to be implemented either". Yes it is, as Benjamin just said. The function is called `count`, not `contains`.

Comment: oh, i missed it.  Perhaps I should have asked that first

Comment: My guess is that this was never considered. It's mostly public record what the committee has considered (people who vote standards-rationale questions closed as opinion-based are simply wrong, and are damaging the site as a programming resource IMO, but that's another story). Unfortunately it's a difficult job to check the record since it's a mix of proposal documents and meeting reports going back 20 years. As Kerrek says, it just doesn't fit the usual iterator operations. I don't think the standard ever bolts convenience functions onto particular iterator types...

Comment: ... and anyway, `bool` conversions in particular are a bit type-unsafe since they're a gateway to other numeric types.

Comment: this question is very valid, now with `explicit operator bool()`

Comment: C++20 to the rescue: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/contains

Answer (score 14):

Iterators in the C++ standard library do not know about the container where they came from, and so they cannot in general know whether they've reached the end. This is deliberate, so as to allow iterators to be as light-weight as possible – you don't pay for what you don't use. (Iterators generalize the idea of pointers, and a pointer is an iterator.)

You can always build your own self-aware iterator as a pair of native iterators.

In fact, some people have argued that such a pair, or *range* is the more natural way to talk about collections, and there are libraries, as well as library adapters, to implement ranges (e.g. Boost.Range).

*Update:* Iterators are more low-level than ranges, and it is debatable which concept is a better solution (though one would need to define the *problem* first). Iterators are a bit more flexible; for example, if you mutate a container while iterating over it, you'd have to "update" all range-pairs to receive the new "end" value. (Or otherwise switch to a completely "range-centered" algorithmic style.) Alternatively you could store a reference to the container in the iterator and recompute `end()` each time it's needed. Already you can see how there are lots of non-trivial details, and the C++ standard library simply decided not to make those choices for you but instead only give you the *building blocks* to write the solution that fits your own problem best.

Comment: This *probably* is the answer, no special case was ever proposed. But the question isn't about iterators in general, it's specifically about `set::iterator`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It'd be difficult to maintain range invariants while you mutate containers, so iterators are probably a more general solution.

Comment: Of course iterators as a whole are more general than `set::iterator` in particular, I can't disagree with that :-) Since set mutation in particular doesn't invalidate iterators (other than the one removed), I don't really see how mutation would seriously obstruct a `set` implementation from implementing `operator bool()` (or something safer) such that end iterators return false and other iterators true.

Comment: It seems like I'd be able to define an explicit cast of `iterator` (and `const_iterator`) to `bool` -- by comparing them with the `end()` (or `cend()`) of the same container -- right there, in the template...

Comment: @MikhailT. I don't even need to compare - for the OP requirement we just need to know if the iterator returned was the `end()` iterator when it was created. Additional mutations should not change the fact that such an end iterator instance is `== end()`. The only deficiency of such implementation is that a non-end iterator that got invalidated (by having its target removed from the container) would not know that it is no longer valid (and hence would, maybe, return `false` from `operator bool()`) - but that will not be a behavior change.